# jquery index on list item issue

Tags: jquery, indexing, listitem

I'm working on getting the index of a list item contained within a UL which has the class called zoomThumbActive.  I've tried just about every selector I can think of and always get -1 (not found).

I've put all the code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuWbK/17/):

In this example, the answer should be 3. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the fiddle page does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index needs to be called on the `li` element since this is the actual element descendant of `ul`. There's only one `a` inside of each `li`.

```
$('#mainImgA').click(function(){
    var idx = $('.zoomThumbActive').parent().index();
    alert(idx);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$('#mainImgA').click(function() {
    var a = $('ul#thumblist li a.zoomThumbActive');
    var i = $('ul#thumblist li a').index(a);
    alert(i);

});
```

UPDATE:

```
$('.zoomThumbActive').index('ul#thumblist li a');
```

That works. I misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: I face the same problem with that overload. is it a bug?

Comment: Not a bug. The selectors were backwards.